# Error while creating a class from SurfaceView, which is to be run as a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, class, android-studio

I know the basic concepts of OOP, I am trying my hands on Android programming.(Games in particular). I am trying to implement a game project from this book Android Game programming by example. I am able to understand theoretically what is being said. But when I put together the pieces of code, into a single java class TDView.java file, I get an error in Android studio. Maybe I misunderstood some phrase and Put a piece where I wasn't suppose to put it.

The errors are labeled error1 and error2 in the code below:

```
package com.gamecodeschool.c1tappydefender;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class TDView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    volatile boolean playing;
    Thread gameThread = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (playing) {
            update();
            draw();
            control();
        } //error2: it says a semicolon is needed here.

        private void update(){
        }
        private void draw(){
        }
        private void control(){
        }
    }// error1: it says class or interface missing

    public TDView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    // Clean up our thread if the game is interrupted or the player quits
    public void pause() {
        playing = false;
        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 

        }
    }

    // Make a new thread and start it
    // Execution moves to our R
    public void resume() {
        playing = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: move the update, draw, and control methods outside of the run method so they are actually methods of the class.

Comment: So basically run is a method that implements(calls) the other three?

Comment: The run method calls the other three yes. You are not allowed to have the methods declared where you have them currently. That is where the errors are coming from.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why did you accept the other answer when I answered you first with basically the same thing?

Comment: "Method declaration" that term made the fact sink in. I am thankful though. I hope it is not wrong in any way.

Comment: Fair enough thanks for the explanation. I can certainly see how that would have been confusing looking back now even though, I did mention "declared" in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your method declaration outside of the declaration of your run method. this should do the trick

```
public void run() {
  while (playing) {
    update();
    draw();
    control();
  }
}

private void update(){
}

private void draw(){
}

private void control(){
}
```

Comment: yes that fixed it up. So it is never possible to nest a function definition inside another? like we have nested classes?.

Comment: yes, not in a function directly. you can do it, if you use for example lambda expressions, but i think this is a little to complex for a beginner ;). But if you are hooked, here is some quick start: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html)

Comment: If you could add the link with the answer, it would help future references.

Comment: Of course, but the link is per se is not relevant to the question. It's an answer to the follow up question in the comment :)